# How to make components load only once in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React to realize following: in the Main page, if users click one button, will load Child page, if not then load another child page.
The problem is the Child component is loading repeatedly because I can check in console that the 'load function' is being printed nonstop. How can I let the child component only load(refresh) once when user clicks the button? Thanks!

In main.jsx:

```
import {Child} from "../Child";
export const Main = (props) => {
    ....
    if (props.ButtonClicked) {
          showPortal = <Child />
    } else {
          showPortal = <AnotherChild />
    }
    ....
}
```

in Child.jsx:

```
export const Child = ()=> {
    console.log('load function')
    return (<div>test</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are trying to do because you haven't post your whole code.

But something like this should work.

```
 export default class Comp extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {
          clicked: false,
         };
      }

      onClickFunction() {
       this.setState({
         clicked: true,
       });
     }
      render() {
        const d = this.state.clicked && <Child />;
        return (
           <div>
             <button onClick={this.onClickFunction.bind(this)}></button>
             {d}
           </div>
         );
        }
     }

     const Child = () => {
      console.log("load function");
      return <div>test</div>;
    };
```

Comment: Hi @DimitrisBovasianos, sorry for the unclarity, I have updated the question and this two components are in different files.

Comment: Can you post the whole code from your main.js file ? I guess the communication between your button and the state you have it's not the  correct one that's why it is loaded every time.